# jwPlayer - Switching out XML Playlists with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I wish I could show an example of this, but I will try to explain as best as I can.

I have jwPlayer 5.7 integrated into a client's webpage. The playlist is fed from an XML file composed of around 120 videos. Some of these videos are split into 4-part series. The client would prefer that when these videos are selected that playlist would show the 4 videos in the series and those 4 videos alone.

```
$(function() {

    buildPlayer();

    function buildPlayer() {

        jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
        'autostart': 'false',
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'id': 'playerID',
        'width': '960',
        'height': '400',
        'file': 'videos.xml',
        'modes': [
                    {type: 'flash', src: '/jwplayer/player.swf'},
                    {type: 'html5'},
                    {type: 'download'}
            ],
        'skin': 'skywalker.zip',
        'playlist.position': 'right',
        'playlist.size': '300'
        });
    };


    // On playlist Item change... 
    jwplayer().onPlaylistItem(function(event) {

        var curItem = (event.index);
        console.log('index change..' + curItem);

        if (curItem == 0) {
            jwplayer('mediaplayer').play(); 
        }
        else if (curItem == 74) {
            jwplayer().load([{file:"video-series-1.xml"}]);
            return false;   
        }
        else {
            console.log('not webinar');
            jwplayer().load([{file:"media-feed.xml"}]);
            jwplayer('mediaplayer').play(); 
        }
    });
});
```

This works, to an extent. The playlist will change to the "series" XML file. But after I click on a link with the function:

```
jwplayer().playlistItem(57);
```

The jwplayer().onPlaylistItem function will not trigger. I imagine because this playlist does not have a video with an index of 57 (It is only 4 videos total).

Comment: Did you try  changing the link to: jwplayer().playlistItem(0) or jwplayer().playlistItem(3)?

From the sounds of your question, the XML library is working, but the link isn't?

Comment: If possible, can you put up a demo?

Comment: Hey Ethan - at the moment, I cannot.. we have a very privately-secured staging environment.

Stingey - Right now the html has an onclick attribute. Like so: <a onclick="jwplayer().playlistItem(62)"> .. So when the user clicks this tag, the index of 62 (their are only 4 videos in the new playlist) does not exist. It seems jwPlayer just ignores the jwplayer().onPlaylistItem event when the index does not exist.

Ethan - Is their another event I can tap into if the index does not exist?